# Azure Mobile Services token validation in Web API and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services, jwt

I have a Xamarin mobile app that uses the Azure Mobile Services SDK to authenticate a user against social providers. I get the token and attach it to http request hitting my Web API ASP.NET application (that I'm deploying as an Azure Cloud Service) as a bearer token.

I need to validate the bearer token and get a ClaimsIdentity to work with in my ApiController. Do I need to use the Mobile Service .NET Backend nuget packages for this? How can I?

EDIT:

1. Created an empty ASP.NET application Added a Web API controller
2. Installed Mobile Services .NET Backend nuget package
3. Set appsettings values for keys MS_MobileServiceName, MS_MasterKey,
   MS_ApplicationKey from values in Azure Management Console
4. Set [AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.User)] on my HttpGet operation
   in my ApiController
5. Cast User to ServiceUser
6. Create http request with bearer token from Google Auth thru Azure
   Mobile Service SDK
7. User is null!

Answer (score 0):

Use attributes such as

```
[AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]

[AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.User)]
```

On the methods in your API to validate depending on which role you want.

Then use

```
var currentUser = User as ServiceUser;
```

to get the current user in the method, if the AuthorizationLevel is not Anonymous.

And setup your AppSettings as necessary. Change the MasterKey and ApplicationKey if you are testing the MobileService on localhost.

```
 <appSettings>
    <!-- Use these settings for local development. After publishing to 
    Mobile Services, these settings will be overridden by the values specified
    in the portal. -->
    <add key="MS_MobileServiceName" value="[NAME HERE]" />
    <add key="MS_MasterKey" value="[INSERT HERE]" />
    <add key="MS_ApplicationKey" value="[INSERT HERE]" />
    <add key="MS_MicrosoftClientID" value="Overridden by portal settings" />
    <add key="MS_MicrosoftClientSecret" value="Overridden by portal settings" />
    <add key="MS_FacebookAppID" value="Overridden by portal settings" />
    <add key="MS_FacebookAppSecret" value="Overridden by portal settings" />
    <add key="MS_GoogleClientID" value="Overridden by portal settings" />
    <add key="MS_GoogleClientSecret" value="Overridden by portal settings" />
    <add key="MS_TwitterConsumerKey" value="Overridden by portal settings" />
    <add key="MS_TwitterConsumerSecret" value="Overridden by portal settings" />
    <add key="MS_AadClientID" value="Overridden by portal settings" />
    <add key="MS_AadTenants" value="Overridden by portal settings" />
    <!-- When using this setting, be sure to also set the Notification Hubs connection
    string named "MS_NotificationHubConnectionString". -->
    <add key="MS_NotificationHubName" value="Overridden by portal settings" />
    <add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" value="Endpoint=sb://[your namespace].servicebus.windows.net;SharedSecretIssuer=owner;SharedSecretValue=[your secret]" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Surely I have to set some kind of Authentication provider in my WebApiConfig and put my master key in somewhere, right?

Comment: Well you need the Azure Mobile Services .NET Backend package from NuGet. The Master and ApplicationKey are stored in the Web.Config. But that is all.

Comment: Could you provide some code examples for doing that? I'm not finding how to register in the WebApiConfig.

Comment: I don't have anything registered in the WebApiConfig.  I just have https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend/ and place the master and application key in the Web.Config (not WebApiConfig) - AppSettings sections

Comment: What are the appSettings keys you use?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Are you sure you're started with a ASP.NET Empty Application and are deploying as a Cloud Service? I have added the 3 keys to my web.config and my clients add the bearer token to the http request, I added AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.User) as an attribute to my API method, but when I cast to ServiceUser I get null.

Comment: I think the mix up here is you said "MobileService", this isn't a mobile service.. it's a vanilla Web API.

Comment: Have you installed the MobileServices Backend NuGet Package on your WebAPI?

Comment: Just to elaborate, if you are using the Mobile Service Client package then you need to use the Mobile Services backend to have easy access to the authentication it uses. You can install the mobile services backend on a Vanilla WebAPI.